Stripe Primary and secondary subscription
using a customer portal to update primary subscription(Basic, Standard, Premium)
user can end up updating primary into secondary and vise versa which could be totally messed up
my secondary subscription is like addons support that has trial period and one time payment.
if i go to customer portal where subscriptions are listed that are subscribed but once you go to update plan button you will also see all the addons as well
and same goes for addons subscription, if you want to update into other addon you will see a list of all primary subscriptions
how can i resolve that conflict or there is another way
i could try not to use customer portal at all to update subscription of any kind do everything custom

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
